# export data to cisco call manager 8.0

Tags: .net, cisco

I have my users Phone usage data with Phone Number, Authorization code,Access Level,Extension Number and other  details.

I want to send these details to CISCO Call Manager 8.0 to access the FAC(Forced Authorization code) and Call Rate Details and other functions for my CISCO IP Phone to force the user to enter their FAC code to make a phone call.

How to Send data to call manager from my application (Developed in .net 3.0 with c#).

Is any interface is required to process the data.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way , you can feed the data that you have to the call manager .
Meaning call records , and usage details .
however if there are some phones to be added in system you can always use  (BAT - bulk addition tool )  to upload many number of phones .